# Slim PHP - route callback problems with new Slim 3.1

Tags: php, slim

I have just upgraded from Slim 2 to Slim 3.1.
Here is my code:

```
require_once(PROJECT_ROOT . 'api/vendor/autoload.php');
class API
{
    public function __construct( ) {

        $this->slimObj = new \Slim\App;

        $this->initAPI();

        $this->slimObj->run();
    }
    private function initAPI () 
    {
        $this->slimObj->get('/first/:ID', array($this, 'callback')); 
    }
    function callback( $ID ) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

When I call `myserver.php/first/1` I get `Page Not Found` error.
What is wrong with my code?

Thanks

Comment: You may read that upgrade guide, the functions parameter inside ->get() are now different.

Comment: also it not :ID anymore it is {ID}